# SDL: How to render multiple different textures based on mouse event

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to make a simple menu with 3 different options. Play, Options, Exit.

I want them to change colors when you hover over them and when you mouse up on them. I tried using lazy foo's reference for mouse events, but I'm confused on how to do it with different "buttons". It would be one thing if they were saying all the same thing.

Here is my code:

```
#include "Menu.h"
#include <iostream>

std::string tmpCap;

SDL_Color tmpColor;
SDL_Color colorW = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
SDL_Color colorG1 = { 65, 65, 65, 255 };
SDL_Color colorG2 = { 85, 85, 85, 255 };
SDL_Color colorG3 = { 125, 125, 125, 255 };

SDL_Texture* currentPlaySet[3];
SDL_Texture* currentOptionsSet[3];
SDL_Texture* currentExitSet[3];


SDL_Texture* currentPlay;
SDL_Texture* currentOptions;
SDL_Texture* currentExit;
SDL_Texture* currentTexboo[3];

enum mMenuNum
{
    PLAY_MOUT = 0,
    PLAY_MON = 1,
    PLAY_MUP = 2,
    OPTIONS_MOUT = 3,
    OPTIONS_MON = 4,
    OPTIONS_MUP = 5,
    EXIT_MOUT = 6,
    EXIT_MON = 7,
    EXIT_MUP = 8,
    MENUNUM_TOTAL = 9
};

enum mCheckButton
{
    B_OUT = 0,
    B_ON = 1,
    B_UP = 2,
    B_TOTAL = 3
};

int xCenter = 1024 / 2;
int yCenter = 768 / 2;

SDL_Rect rtmp[3];


SDL_Texture* btmp[9];


class Button
{
    public:
        //Initializes internal variables
        Button();

        //Sets top left position
        void setPosition( int x, int y );

        void setSize(int x, int y, int w, int h);

        //Handles mouse event
        void handleEvent(SDL_Event* e);

        //Shows button sprite
        void renderButtons();

    private:
        //Top left position
        SDL_Point mPosition;

        SDL_Rect mSize;

        //Currently used global sprite
        mCheckButton mCurrentSprite;

};

void Menu::init()
{
    const char* buttonCaptions[3] = {
        "  Play  ", "  Options  ", "  Exit  "
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(i < 3)
        {
            tmpCap = buttonCaptions[0];
        }
        if(i < 6 && i > 2)
        {
            tmpCap = buttonCaptions[1];
        }
        if(i < 9 && i > 5)
        {
            tmpCap = buttonCaptions[2];
        }
        if(i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6)
        {
            tmpColor = colorG1;
        }
        if(i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7)
        {
            tmpColor = colorG2;
        }
        if(i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8)
        {
            tmpColor = colorG3;
        }

        btmp[i] = TextureManager::TextTexture("../src/assets/Arial Black.ttf", tmpCap, 40, tmpColor);
        //std::cout << tmpCap << " " << i << std::endl;

    }

    currentPlaySet[0] = btmp[0];
    currentOptionsSet[0] = btmp[3];
    currentExitSet[0] = btmp[6];


    currentPlaySet[1] = btmp[1];
    currentOptionsSet[1] = btmp[4];
    currentExitSet[1] = btmp[7];


    currentPlaySet[2] = btmp[2];
    currentOptionsSet[2] = btmp[5];
    currentExitSet[2] = btmp[8];
    Menu::getSize();

}
Button::Button()
{
    currentPlay = btmp[0];
    currentOptions = btmp[3];
    currentExit = btmp[6];


    mCurrentSprite = B_OUT;
}
Button f[9];
void Button::setPosition(int x, int y)
{
    mPosition.x = x;
    mPosition.y = y;
}
void Button::setSize(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    mSize.x = x;
    mSize.y = y;
    mSize.w = w;
    mSize.h = h;
}
void Menu::getSize()
{
    SDL_QueryTexture(btmp[0], NULL, NULL, &rtmp[0].w, &rtmp[0].h);


    int aX = xCenter - (rtmp[0].w / 2);
    int aY = (yCenter - (rtmp[0].h / 2)) - 100;
    int aW = rtmp[0].w;
    int aH = rtmp[0].h;
    f[0].setPosition(aX, aY);
    f[0].setSize(aX, aY, aW, aH);


    SDL_QueryTexture(btmp[3], NULL, NULL, &rtmp[1].w, &rtmp[1].h);
    int bX = xCenter - (rtmp[1].w / 2);
    int bY = (yCenter - (rtmp[1].h / 2));
    int bW = rtmp[1].w;
    int bH = rtmp[1].h;
    f[1].setPosition(bX, bY);
    f[1].setSize(bX, bY, bW, bH);

    SDL_QueryTexture(btmp[6], NULL, NULL, &rtmp[2].w, &rtmp[2].h);
    int cX = xCenter - (rtmp[2].w / 2);
    int cY = (yCenter - (rtmp[2].h / 2)) + 100;
    int cW = rtmp[2].w;
    int cH = rtmp[2].h;
    f[2].setPosition(cX, cY);
    f[2].setSize(cX, cY, cW, cH);

}
void Button::handleEvent(SDL_Event* e)
{
    if( e->type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION || e->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN || e->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP )
    {
        int x, y;
        SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);

        //Check if mouse is in button
        bool inside = true;

        //Mouse is left of the button
        if( x < mPosition.x )
        {
            inside = false;
        }
        //Mouse is right of the button
        else if( x > mPosition.x + mSize.w )
        {
            inside = false;
        }
        //Mouse above the button
        else if( y < mPosition.y )
        {
            inside = false;
        }
        //Mouse below the button
        else if( y > mPosition.y + mSize.h )
        {
            inside = false;
        }

        //Mouse is outside button
        if( !inside )
        {
            std::cout << "Outside " << " " << mCurrentSprite << std::endl;
            //currentPlay = currentPlaySet[mCurrentSprite];
            //currentOptions = currentOptionsSet[mCurrentSprite];
            //currentExit = currentExitSet[mCurrentSprite];
            mCurrentSprite = B_OUT;
        }
        //Mouse is inside button
        else
        {
            switch( Game::event.type )
            {
                case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                mCurrentSprite = B_ON;
                //currentPlay = btmp[(mCurrentSprite/3)+1];
                //currentOptions = btmp[(mCurrentSprite/3)+1];
                //currentExit = btmp[(mCurrentSprite/3)+1];
                //currentPlay = currentPlaySet[mCurrentSprite];
                //currentOptions = currentOptionsSet[mCurrentSprite];
                //currentExit = currentExitSet[mCurrentSprite];

                std::cout << "In " << mCurrentSprite << std::endl;
                break;

                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                //currentPlay = currentPlaySet[mCurrentSprite];
                //currentOptions = currentOptionsSet[mCurrentSprite];
                //currentExit = currentExitSet[mCurrentSprite];
                //mCurrentSprite = B_DOWN;
                //currentTex = mTex3;
                break;

                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                //currentPlay = currentPlaySet[mCurrentSprite];
                //currentOptions = currentOptionsSet[mCurrentSprite];
                //currentExit = currentExitSet[mCurrentSprite];
                mCurrentSprite = B_UP;
                //currentTex = mTex4;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
void Button::renderButtons()
{

    while( SDL_PollEvent( &Game::event ) != 0 )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
        {
            f[i].handleEvent(&Game::event);
        //isMouseOverText();
        }
    }

        SDL_RenderCopy(Game::mRenderer, btmp[mCurrentSprite], nullptr, &mSize);
        //SDL_RenderCopy(Game::mRenderer, currentOptionsSet[mCurrentSprite], nullptr, &mSize);
        //SDL_RenderCopy(Game::mRenderer, currentExitSet[mCurrentSprite], nullptr, &mSize);

}
void Menu::render()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        f[i].renderButtons();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using an old SDL tutorial code from [here](https://pastebin.com/Ve3CXyMe).

Is it viable to delete and create these textures on interact?

I've updated my code to avoid deleting textures every time at the bottom. Is there a better way to do this? It seems clean to me but I'm concerned about resource usage.

Any insight is appreciated.

My code:

```
const int NUMMENU = 2;
const char* labels[NUMMENU] = {"Continue","Exit"};
SDL_Texture* menus[NUMMENU];
bool selected[NUMMENU] = {0,0};
SDL_Color color[2] = {{0,0,0,255},{255,0,0,255}};
SDL_Rect pos[NUMMENU];
int x,y;
const char* font = "../assets/Arial Black.ttf";


void MainMenu::init()
{
    menus[0] = TextureManager::CreateFontTexture(font, labels[0], 40, color[0]);
    menus[1] = TextureManager::CreateFontTexture(font, labels[1], 40, color[0]);

    SDL_QueryTexture(menus[0], NULL, NULL, &pos[0].w, &pos[0].h);
    SDL_QueryTexture(menus[1], NULL, NULL, &pos[1].w, &pos[1].h);

    pos[0].x = (1024/2) - (pos[0].w / 2);
    pos[0].y = (768/2) - (pos[0].h / 2) - 100;
    pos[1].x = (1024/2) - (pos[1].w / 2);
    pos[1].y = (768/2) - (pos[1].h / 2);
}

void MainMenu::render()
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(App::appRenderer, menus[0], NULL, &pos[0]);
    SDL_RenderCopy(App::appRenderer, menus[1], NULL, &pos[1]);

    if( App::event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION || App::event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN || App::event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP )
        {
                switch(App::event.type)
                {
                    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                        x = App::event.motion.x;
                        y = App::event.motion.y;
                        for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i += 1) {
                            if(x>=pos[i].x && x<=pos[i].x+pos[i].w && y>=pos[i].y && y<=pos[i].y+pos[i].h)
                            {
                                if(!selected[i])
                                {
                                    selected[i] = 1;
                                    SDL_DestroyTexture(menus[i]);
                                    menus[i] = TextureManager::CreateFontTexture(font, labels[i], 40, color[1]);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(selected[i])
                                {
                                    selected[i] = 0;
                                    SDL_DestroyTexture(menus[i]);
                                    menus[i] = TextureManager::CreateFontTexture(font, labels[i], 40, color[0]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        x = App::event.button.x;
                        y = App::event.button.y;
                        for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i += 1) {
                            if(x>=pos[i].x && x<=pos[i].x+pos[i].w && y>=pos[i].y && y<=pos[i].y+pos[i].h)
                            {
                                SDL_DestroyTexture(menus[0]);
                                SDL_DestroyTexture(menus[1]);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

}
```

UPDATED code without deleting textures every time:

```
const int NUMMENU = 3;
const char* labels[NUMMENU] = {"New Game", "Options","Exit"};

SDL_Texture* menus[NUMMENU];
SDL_Texture* selectedMenus[NUMMENU];
SDL_Texture* toRender[NUMMENU];

bool selected[NUMMENU] = {0,0};

SDL_Color color[2] = {{0,0,0,255},{125,125,125,255}};
SDL_Rect pos[NUMMENU];
int x,y;
const char* font = "../assets/Arial Black.ttf";
int aOne = 0;

void MainMenu::init()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i++)
    {
        menus[i] = TextureManager::CreateFontTexture(font, labels[i], 40, color[0]);
        toRender[i] = menus[i];
        selectedMenus[i] = TextureManager::CreateFontTexture(font, labels[i], 40, color[1]);
        SDL_QueryTexture(menus[i], NULL, NULL, &pos[i].w, &pos[i].h);
    }

    pos[0].x = (1024/2) - (pos[0].w / 2);
    pos[0].y = (768/2) - (pos[0].h / 2) - 100;
    pos[1].x = (1024/2) - (pos[1].w / 2);
    pos[1].y = (768/2) - (pos[1].h / 2);
    pos[2].x = (1024/2) - (pos[2].w / 2);
    pos[2].y = (768/2) - (pos[2].h / 2) + 100;

}

void MainMenu::inputD()
{
    aOne++;
    std::cout << aOne << std::endl;
    switch(App::event.type)
    {
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            x = App::event.motion.x;
            y = App::event.motion.y;
            for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i += 1)
            {
                if(x>=pos[i].x && x<=pos[i].x+pos[i].w && y>=pos[i].y && y<=pos[i].y+pos[i].h)
                {
                    if(!selected[i])
                    {
                        selected[i] = 1;
                        toRender[i] = selectedMenus[i];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(selected[i])
                    {
                        selected[i] = 0;
                        toRender[i] = menus[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x = App::event.button.x;
            y = App::event.button.y;
            for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i += 1)
            {
                if(x>=pos[i].x && x<=pos[i].x+pos[i].w && y>=pos[i].y && y<=pos[i].y+pos[i].h)
                {
                    std::cout << labels[i] << " button clicked" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

void MainMenu::render()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i++)
        SDL_RenderCopy(App::appRenderer, toRender[i], NULL, &pos[i]);
}
```